# html restrictions in ics file

Tags: html, icalendar

I'm developing a function (C#, ASP.NET 4) which creates and downloads a .ics file.

I'm trying to figure out what restrictions there are on the html within the X-ALT-DESC property.  For example, if I send this:

```
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body><ul><li style="font-weight:bold">#1</li><li>#2</li></ul><table border=1><tr><td>table test</td></tr></table><span style="font-weight:bold">Site Visit Agenda</span><br/><span>8:00 AM</span><br/><span>Check in with management<br/>Facility Inspection<br/>Training and Meeting Setup</span></tr></table></body><html>
```

When I open the downloaded file, it opens in Outlook 2010, so that seems o.k.  While the list stuff renders as I'd expect, the table border doesn't show, nor do either of the font-weight settings get rendered.  (On the plus side, the html tags aren't rendered as text, it just doesn't format the alt desc like you'd see in a browser with the same HTML).

Of course, we're trying to figure out what HTML we can and cannot use to format the information we want to show up in the alt description.

Searching around, I can't find anything which talks about what's allowed and what isn't.

Thanks to anyone who has a pointer.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/854036/299327) talks about what is and is not allowed.