# use HTML code in the summary field of an iCalendar feed

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have this simple ics feed:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Remodel or Move//NONSGML v1.0//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:My Scheduler

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@remodelormove.com
DTSTAMP:20121010T080000Z
DTSTART:20121010T080000Z
DTEND:20121010T090000Z
SUMMARY:Compile list of wants
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

I would like to insert an HTML anchor into the summary so that users can click it and be sent off from Google Calendar (or Outlook, ...) to a webpage sitting on my website where they can edit the entry.

I am after something like this:

```
SUMMARY:Compile list of wants <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/edit?id=923">edit</a>
```

I try that but the link is not shown when I import the ics feed into Google Calendar.

How can I achieve what I am after?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the following: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/859475/1167333

Answer (score 2):

re html in summary field - I think that depends very much on the application that subscribes to the ics feed - many will not expect or deal with html.
Google is a bit weird in that last I tried, it allowed on to put in the html when creating an event but then tossed it away if one edited it.
Probably safer NOT to rely on html in the ics file.

Some applications (such as  my wordpress ics plugin) will convert any http links found into 'clickable' links when displaying the event from the ics file.

FYI There is a url field https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.6. which is meant to be the one that provides detail on the event.

BY the way your example looks like it should be a VTODO not a VEVENT ?
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.2

Comment: I have tried to use the URL field but it doesn't seem to be picked up buy Google Calendar or Outlook.