# Method to insert hyperlinks in description field of Icalendar (ics) file

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, thunderbird

I used to insert hyperlinks in ics file using x-alt-desc field which allowed html tags. Issue was that this field only worked woth MS Outlook and I had to use alternate description field which must contain plain text format (\n could be added for new line).

I am now able to get following output now

**Outlook**:
[image]

**Google Calendar**
[image]

**Mozilla Thunderbird**
[image]

Issue is links work best in outlook, still clickable/working in google calendar and plain text in thunderbird. Is there any way I can making them clickable in thunderbird like google calendar??

Comment: Looks like you have the (unsatisfying) answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854036/html-in-ical-attachment)

Comment: @Rossiar Yes, I tried my best to find solution to this problem. It may not even have a solution. I have set up bounty in case if any gurus can help me